# Equivalent of UV Squares in 2.8 to make islands straight?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm starting to use Blender 2.8 and have a question : Is there something like UV Squares that I could use to make my UV islands straight? Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Why not use UV Squares? I got it working in 2.8.

https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-uvsquares-v1-4-updated-any-shape-supported/613111/99

Answer (score 4):

## UV Squares Blender 2.8 code fix/workaround

Download the latest release from github for UV Squares
https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares

Then update the

> uv_squares.py

file in Visual Studio Code or Notepad

To remove the blender 2.8 Upgrade warning change the bl_info section from:

```
bl_info = { “name”: “UV Squares”, “description”: “UV Editor tool for reshaping selection to grid.”, “author”: “Reslav Hollos”, “version”: (1, 5, 0), “blender”: (2, 71, 0), “category”: “Mesh”,
#“location”: “UV Image Editor > UVs > UVs to grid of squares”,
#“warning”: “”, “wiki_url”: “http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares” }
```

TO

```py
bl_info = { “name”: “UV Squares”, “description”: “UV Editor tool for reshaping selection to grid.”, “author”: “Reslav Hollos”, “version”: (1, 5, 0), “blender”: (2, 80, 0), “category”: “Mesh”,
#“location”: “UV Image Editor > UVs > UVs to grid of squares”,
#“warning”: “”, “wiki_url”: “http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares” }
```

Note that only the property of BLENDER has changed in the file to “blender”: (2, 80, 0),
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons

I also had to comment out line 52 of the code to get this working in Blender 2.8, just add a # symbol in from of this line as follows:

```py
#bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()
```

Reinstall the addon and it should work for what most people need.

I’m hoping this addon gets some official love when Blender comes out of Beta soon.

Answer (score 1):

Umwrap mesh (U) > Lightmap Pack > Follow Active Quads

this feature available in blender 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Install both 2.79 & 2.8 version of Blender. Current UV Square which is provided in Github working fine with 2.79 version. Save your UV layout with your model and then open the .blend file in 2.8. This is the only work around at this moment.